# Calculate RA DEC/AZ EL of Lagrange Points seen from a location on earth

Tags: python, astronomy, pyephem, orbital-mechanics, skyfield

I would like to calculate the position of the five Lagrange points in the sky (L1 - L5) as RA/DEC or AZ/EL when provided with a UTC timestamp and a Lat/Lon/Alt observer location on earth. I was looking at pyephem, pyorbital and skyfield but as far as I could see, they do not support this. If someone could point me towards a reference/code to calculating this in python that would be much appreciated.

P.S. If not already a part of pyephem/skyfield/pyorbital, I think this would be an interesting feature to add?

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert arbitrary (geocentric or heliocentric) position vectors into RA/DEC, the solution is straightforward, as you can compute the position vectors of the Lagrange points relatively easily.

If you have the geocentric position vector of the Sun, `Rsun`, you can do the following:

Since L1, L2 and L3 are on the Sun-Earth line, they are just differently scaled versions of `Rsun`. Here are some pretty good approximations that work because the mass of the Sun is much bigger than the mass of the Earth (the exact formulas are much more complicated):

`L1 = Rsun * (m / (3*M))**(1/3)`

`L2 = -Rsun * (m / (3*M))**(1/3)`

`L3 = Rsun * (2 + (5*m / (12*M))`

where the mass units don't matter so we can use Earth mass as the unit so that `m == 1` is the Earth's mass and `M == 333000` is the Sun's mass.

The L4 and L5 points are corners of equilateral triangles with the Sun and the Earth. Therefore you can get them by rotating `Rsun` by 60° and –60° around the normal of the orbital plane (usually the z-axis in an ecliptical coordinate system). This is easy, the pseudocode is:

```
# Get the three components of the original vector
x,y,z = Rsun 

# Compute the rotated vector
L4 = [
  x * cos(60°) - y * sin(60°),
  x * sin(60°) + y * cos(60°),
  z 
]
```